# IE limits to 2083 chars when using get method to call a javascript function

Tags: javascript, xml, internet-explorer, post, get

I'm trying to pass a long string of xml to a javascript function. Currently the call works something like this, I have an xsl file that generates the html code and in the code it generates a link that does this.

```
<a href="javascript:myFunctionName('long xml string')">My Link</a>
```

I know that using the post method would get around the limit by IE of 2083 characters but am not sure on the best way to go about it.

Comment: `GET`/`POST` methods have nothing do do with your problem as you are calling local `JS` function and not navigation to `HREF`... but YES, IE has a nasti limit of 1024 (as far as I know) character of **string literals**. You should be able to work around the problem by using concatenation to build a string...

Comment: The limit is INTERNET_MAX_URL_LENGTH in wininet.h.

Answer (score 1):

It's possibly due to IE's URL length limit, which is affecting you because the script is in the `href` attribute. You could try changing it to:

```
<a href="#" onclick="return myFunctionName('long xml string')">My Link</a>
```

You may need to return false from your function and/or do some other stuff in order to prevent the default click event.

Alternatively you can move your Javascript out into a separate area and bind a function to the onclick property of the link from there.

Answer (score 0):

This post my help you

http://bytes.com/topic/javascript/answers/790925-overcomming-ies-2083-byte-url-restriction